# Assign value to cell in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am iterating through the file and want to set value of cell in `DataFrame` based on index and column.

```
f = "D:/Technical_Data/1pep.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(f, header=0, sep=',')
save_file = "D:/Result_of_TA/" + "def.csv"
qbfile = open(save_file,"r")
for aline in qbfile.readlines():
    values = aline.split(",")
    if values[58].strip()=='BUY' :
       no_of_shares = price/float(values[4])
    if values[58].strip()=='SELL' :
        price = no_of_shares * float(values[4]) 
    df.ix[values[0],'Price'] = price
qbfile.close()
df.to_csv(save_file)
```

I am getting below error

```
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3979)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 152, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3782)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 178, in pandas.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates (pandas\index.c:4213)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 385, in pandas.index.Int64Engine._maybe_get_bool_indexer (pandas\index.c:7683)
KeyError: '20150101'
```

The column 0 in both file is index

Comment: Can you post a couple rows of your data?

Comment: Do you *really* mean to overwrite your `save_file`?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading in both `csv` files with `pandas` instead of looping thru `save_file`. You can then create various indexing schemes and calculations to move data from `qb` to `1pep`.  You can structure your code *something* like this

```
import pandas as pd

# File locations
pep1_file = 'D:/Technical_Data/1pep.csv'
qb_file = 'D:/Result_of_TA/def.csv.csv'

# Read csv files
pep1 = pd.read_csv(pep1_file, header=0, sep=',')
qb = pd.read_csv(qb_file, header=0, sep=',')

# Process data    
# Find rows with buy in 58th col?
buy_index = qb.iloc[:, 58].str.contains('BUY')

# Find rows with sell in 58th col?
sell_index = qb.iloc[:, 58].str.contains('SELL')

# Get something from 4th col in buy rows?
something_from_purchase = qb.ix[buy_index, 4].astype(float)

# Derive number of shares 
# Where do you get your initial price from?
# It is used before it is assigned if buy row happens first in the original code?
no_of_shares = price / something_from_purchase

# Get something from 4th col in sell rows?
something_from_sale = qb.ix[sell_index, 4].astype(float)

# Derive price
# Where do you get your initial no_of_shares from?
# It is used before it is assigned if sell row happens first in the original code?
price = no_of_shares * something_from_sale

# Assign pep1 price based on qb index
pep1.loc[qb.index, 'Price'] = price

# Then write csv file
# Are sure you want to overwrite?
pep1.to_csv(qb_file)
```

Right now your code is not clear. There are some initial value dependancies (`no_of_shares` and `price`) that seem to be circular and some of the calculations seem possibly backwards. Without some example data or an explanation of the structure, concrete code cannot be suggested.